# Output for reversing a string does not come as expected

Tags: java, string

> Chandu is a bad student. Once his teacher asked him to print the reverse of a given string. He took three hours to solve it. The teacher got agitated at Chandu and asked you the same question. Can you solve it?

**Input**

The first line contains an integer T, denoting the number of test cases.
Each test case contains a string S, comprising of only lower case letters.

**Output**

For each test case, print the reverse of the string S.

**Constraints**

1 <= T <= 10
1 <= |S| <= 30

```
 Input                      Sample Output(Plaintext Link)

 2
 ab                          ba
 aba                         aba
```

**Time Limit**

1 sec(s) for each input file.

**Memory Limit**

256 MB

**Source Limit**

1024 KB

**MyApproach1**

**MyApproach2**

To reverse a string I used XOR logic to reverse the string.

@Edit

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= T; ++i)
    {
        String input = sc.next();
        int len = input.length();
        StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder(len);

        int end = input.length()-1;
        int start = 0;
        while (start<end)
        {
            input1.setCharAt(start,input.charAt(start)^input.charAt(end));
            input1.setCharAt(end,input.charAt(end)^input.charAt(start));
            input1.setCharAt(start,input.charAt(start)^input.charAt(end));

            ++start;
            --end;
        }
        System.out.println(input1.toString());
    }
}
```

I am still getting the following error.

How do I correct this?

Comment: Your code works well.

Comment: There must be some other error being printed before the "non-zero exit code". Check all of your output.

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow questions and answers are meant to be viewed by future readers too. If you keep removing parts of your question that people have already been answered, it makes it hard for future readers to understand the question and the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For approach 1, all you need to do is remove the call to `sc.nextLine()` and everything will be fine. That's because each line contains a "token" i.e. a word, delimited by whitespace. That's what `sc.next()` will return. No need to call `nextLine()` after that.

For your approach 2, you should carefully read the [API documentation of StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). This shows you how to create a String from a StringBuilder, and vice versa. (Whenever I write Java code, I have a browser window with the API documentation for quick reference next to my editor window. It's very useful.)

Edit (after the latest edit to the question):

There is a compilation problem and a runtime problem. First, the XOR operator produces a result of type int, even if its operands are char. So you should put your expression in parentheses and cast it to char. Once you've done that, you'll get a runtime error because you are trying to index an element of a StringBuilder which does not yet exist. When you created the StringBuilder like this:

```
StringBuilder input1=new StringBuilder(len);
```

len is the initial capacity. The value of the StringBuilder instance is initially "". You then call setCharAt() but the current size of the StringBuilder is 0, so you get an index-out-of-bounds exception. You need to initialise the StringBuilder with the string itself:

```
StringBuilder input1=new StringBuilder(input);
```

Now you won't get an exception, but you'll get the wrong answer. That's because of a problem with your XOR logic.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
sc.nextInt();
```

write

```
sc.nextLine();
```

before starting first loop.
For the two lines of your code

```
String s1 = sc.next();
sc.nextLine();
```

write just

```
String s1 = sc.nextLine();
```

The next() function gives you characters before a space while next line gives you whole line.

It'll work Fine.

Comment: When you say "it is not working fine", it is not helpful. This applies both to your comment and to your question. Say exactly how it is not working and give any error messages etc.

Comment: Output is not expected.When I changed the code I am getting:Input 2

ab Output I get: ba.But I need to enter input 2 times and get Output 2 times.

Comment: When I did with my code.I get the following Output.I am editing the Code.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Please See the Code and tell me what is not understood

Comment: Corrected. We have to pass the next line after integer Input.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I have edited the code.What problems I faced now.

Comment: @Jasonarora you wrote "I am still getting the following error" but then didn't say what the error was.

Comment: I'll append the answer regarding your edit to my original answer.